# Adding an event listener to listView

Tags: android

```
getSherlockActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), 
             "You selected :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

I am trying to add an event listener to my activity, but the toast message is not shown at all. I am calling this piece of code from `onCreateView` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you are actually setting the click listener on your list, you are just creating it, and not even keeping a reference to it.

try like this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)(getSherlockActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list));
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), 
             "You selected :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getSherlockActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position,
    long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), 
         "You selected :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}});
```

**EDITED**

```
((ListView)getSherlockActivity()).findViewById(android.R.id.list).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position,
    long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), 
         "You selected :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}});
```

Add this line inside onCreate().

Comment: I don't think this will work, because findViewById() returns a plain `View` and `View` doesn't have method `setOnItemClickListener()` it needs to be cast to ListView before you can call that method I think.

Comment: @FoamyGuy: Good catch! I missed to type cast it. Edited my ans above.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you adding anything. All you did was `findViewById()` for no purpose (as you did not used return value. Also you just created new `OnItemClickListener` for no reason as you do not use it either. And no, putting two lines of code next to each other won't make then automagically interact in any way...

Right approach is:

```
ListView v = (ListView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
v.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Only add

```
ListView lv = (ListView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long id) {

}
```

and Activity should implement `OnItemClickListener`

or

```
ListView lv = (ListView)getSherlockActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long id) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of weeks ago, I found same situation. I didn't use Sherlock but, it may help to set following line.

```
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

Also make sure to set clickable false to any Button in your row item.